# 2-Functor preserves left-exactness of localization

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, 2-categories

Let $C$, $D$ be categories and let $F\dashv G:C\rightleftarrows D$ be an adjunction such that the left adjoint $F$ preserves finite limits. Suppose $J:Cat\rightarrow Cat$ is a 2-functor. Does it hold that  $J(F)$ preserves finite limits?

Comment: What if $J$ is a constant?

Comment: @IttayWeiss Then it would send both $C$ and $D$ to some category $K$ and $J(F)$ would be the identity functor on $K$, which preserves limits. Am I missing something big?

Comment: You mention left exactness, and it's of course very rare for a left adjoint to preserve limits-do you mean finite limits?

Comment: @Kevin Carlson Yes, Editted.

Comment: Are $C$ and $D$ supposed to be small? If not, is $J$ an endofunctor of [$\mathbf{CAT}$](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/CAT), the big category of [large categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/large+category)?